# The number of likes is different between Facebook (website) and the graph-API. Something or someone has disappeared?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, counter

On some comment on FB, i can read "1 Like". However, when I hover the "*1 Like*" the message which appears is "*no one currently likes this*" ! But someone did!

I guess the liker has disappeared from Facebook or something like that... 
But how can I find a real explanation? Does Facebook talk about that case ?

You want a concrete example?
http://www.facebook.com/196925003746/posts/10150386645583747
Some comments of this post have "likes", but when you hover it, it says : "*no one currently likes this*".

When I access to this post from the Graph API, the "like-count" of the comment is still at "1 Like", but if I ask for the list of likers, I haven't got any answer ( I ask for the list with the FB-Graph-Explorer and the {COMMENT_ID}/likes endpoint )

Does somebody have information about it? Does somebody knows more?
It needs to be documented!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug, I filed it for you here:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/512623435469602

you can subscribe to follow it.